# Can we expand the migration request options to include softwarerecs

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I recently noticed the option to migrate a question to Meta in the close reasons. I'm wondering if this could be expanded to include https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

I've seen http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8646/activate-migration-paths-to-unix-and-linux-should-we which was the only related question I could find here and while I understand the concerns over at U & L I think it would be useful both for us and for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ to route primarily opinion based questions such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833413/how-to-download-non-youtube-videos-in-ubuntu-16-04) about what software to use to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

I think such questions would be welcome there and believe this would be a useful time-saving tool for us. Of course the option of commenting and suggesting it as a better alternative exists along with flagging it for moderator intervention, but I think it would be far quicker and more effective for both the reviewer and the mods if we could simply point it to the right site directly from the review queue.

Comment: I don't think such questions are off-topic here...

Comment: migrate to meta has been there for along time? and moving other stuff: doubtful.

Comment: @Zanna Would you not agree that such questions are primarily opinion based?

Comment: Broadly speaking I guess so, but I'm not the biggest fan of that close reason and if OP specifies use case and features required in appropriate detail they can be good valid questions imho... there are some other meta posts "are software recommendations off topic?" etc (I would look for link but on mobile!) And I think the consensus is they are on topic...

Comment: @Zanna Be that as it may, the question that prompted this one is vague and provides no specific use case (and as such would be closed at softwarerecs) and still deserves to be closed here.

Comment: And if it would be closed over there, then we shouldn't migrate it ;)

Comment: @Zanna I see that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would seem to be a bad idea due to the likelihood of misuse. The question linked as an example would [NOT be welcome](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com due to it's vagueness. It seems to me that it lacks sufficient information for a quality answer and should be closed here as well (although I left a comment requesting specifics so that might change).

Sources:

[Are software recommendations on topic or not?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14394/are-software-recommendations-on-topic-or-not)

https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: If the tool can be misused, it shouldn’t be a reason to reject the suggestion.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim The only answer to this question ATM is my opinion which appears to be shared by 3 others in the community. Feel free to add your own.